# Dynamic Recipient from custom object field in Salesforce integrated with DocuSign

Tags: javascript, email, dynamic, salesforce, docusignapi

We have a custom object called "X" and we have DocuSign linked to it. I need to customize a custom button so that it auto populates the DocuSign Envelope's Recipient section using a custom field called email in X
Here is what I have done currently and what is the requirement

a. Name of the field in the custom object X is Email__c (type text)

b. I have kept the **Add recipients section blank in the Docusign panel** ,however in doing so I am loosing out on all the custom tags which I had set for the template.

c. I have created a custom button and the contents are

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [
SourceID = X.Id ,
CCRM = 'Decision Maker~Signer 1',
CCTM = 'Decision Maker~Signer',
DST = '873cd9f7-c905-4340-996e-e166e3594a1c',
**CRL = 'Email~' +X.Email__c ,**
OCO = 'Send',
LA = '0',
LF = '0',
OCO = 'Tag'
]
)}
```

Now the problem is

1. If I have the default recipient and role set here then the emails are being sent here,but the requirement is to make it dynamic.

   [image]

2. If I am using the above code piece for the javascript button url then it is opening up the document where I am unable to create any custom tags and it is saying must select one recipient with name and email to send the mail

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your template is set up correctly (Role Name is filled in as something like `Signer 1`, Name and Email are empty) on the DocuSign side, it's easiest to set this up via the Envelope Configurations section rather than try to build a custom button by hand. Documentation on how to do that is available in the DocuSign Support Center: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Envelope

In short, on the Salesforce side navigate to the 'All Items' menu > DocuSign Envelope Configurations > New.

From there, you can relate the configuration to the template in the 'Documents' section.